# How to left-join one table only?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have this kind of two tables, one is for keeping text, etc, another one is to keep image info,

`pages table`,

```
pg_id     pg_content    parent_id 
10        xxx           3         
11        xxx           3  
12        xxx           3
```

`image table`,

```
img_id    pg_id   img_order     cat_id
1         10      1             1
2         10      1             2
3         10      2             2
4         11      1             1
```

So I want to list all the pages with the `img_order` 1 image from `cat_id` 1 only, but I get duplicated rows when a page has images in `cat_id` 2,

```
SELECT*
FROM root_pages

LEFT JOIN root_images_pages
ON root_images_pages.pg_id = root_pages.pg_id

WHERE root_pages.parent_id = '3'
AND root_pages.pg_id != '3'
AND (root_images_pages.img_order = '1' OR  root_images_pages.img_id is NULL)

ORDER BY root_pages.pg_created DESC
LIMIT 12
```

How can I fix it?

I result I want is,

```
pg_id     pg_content    parent_id     img_id    pg_id   img_order     cat_id    
    10        xxx           3          1         10      1             1         
    11        xxx           3          4         11      1             1  
    12        xxx           3          null      null    null          null
```

**EDIT:**

I have to add this line below to the query otherwise the page with no images cannot be listed,

```
AND (i.img_order = '1' OR i.img_id is NULL)
```

So here it is,

```
SELECT*
FROM root_pages p

LEFT JOIN root_images_pages i
ON i.pg_id = p.pg_id and i.cat_id = 1

WHERE p.parent_id = '3'
AND p.pg_id != '3'
AND p.pg_hide != '1'
AND (i.img_order = '1' OR i.img_id is NULL)

ORDER BY p.pg_created DESC
LIMIT 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this, I think that by adding the cat_id criteria to your join you may get the data you're looking for:

```
SELECT*
FROM root_pages r

LEFT JOIN root_images_pages i
ON i.pg_id = r.pg_id and i.cat_id = 1

WHERE r.parent_id = '3'

ORDER BY r.pg_created DESC
LIMIT 12
```

after seeing your edit I think you need to switch the JOIN condition.

```
LEFT JOIN root_images_pages i
ON r.pg_id = i.pg_id and i.cat_id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! it is near to the answer I am looking for! have a look in my edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Exclude cat_id=2 in the where clause?

```
WHERE .... AND (root_images_pages.cat_id <> 2)
```

or explicitly allow only cat_id=1?

```
WHERE .... AND (root_images_pages.cat_id = 1)
```

Comment: it will duplicate if I have two or more images with `cat_id = 1` for `pg_id = 10`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a subquery to select your pages and then left join your root images

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        *
    FROM 
        root_images_pages
    WHERE
        cat_id = 1
    ) AS i
    LEFT JOIN root_pages AS p
    ON i.pg_id = p.pg_id
```

Comment: this will cause a problem when I have pages without any image.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Marc has the correct answer.  But I also don't think you need:

```
OR  root_images_pages.img_id is NULL
```

Assuming img_id is a primary key.